# Richtig oder falsch: »keines der Daten«

Tags: grammar, gender

Unmittelbar oberhalb einer Liste mit Kontaktdaten von Vereinsmitgliedern möchte ich diesen (oder einen ähnlichen) Satz hinschreiben:

> Ohne die ausdrückliche Einwilligung der jeweiligen Person darf keines der hier angezeigten Daten an Personen außerhalb des Vereins weitergegeben werden.

Ich halte diesen Satz zwar für grammatikalisch richtig, dennoch klingt die Phrase

> **keines der Daten**

für mich irgendwie falsch.

Der Singular von »Daten« ist »Datum«, und dieses Wort ist sächlich, so wie auch *Brot*, *Kind* und *Auto*. Daher kann man damit diese gleich gebauten Phrasen bilden, die jedoch keineswegs falsch, sondern völlig korrekt klingen:

> keines der Brote
>   keines der Kinder
>   keines der Autos

Wenn ich ein anderes Geschlecht nehme, klingt es im Fall der Daten auch nicht besser (was auch nicht zu erwarten war):

> männlich: keiner der Daten - keiner der Bäume/Männer/Berge
>   weiblich: keine der Daten - keine der Blumen/Frauen/Glocken

1. Woran liegt es, dass *keines der Daten* falsch klingt?
2. Wie könnte man den Hinweis besser formulieren?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es gibt im Deutschen mittlerweile zwei getrennte Vokabeln *Datum* bzw. *Daten:*

- *[Datum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Datum)* im Sinne von *Termin, Zeitpunkt.* Dies ist ein ganz normales Wort mit allen Deklinationsformen.
- *[Daten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Daten)* im Sinne von *Informationen, Messergebnisse, Fakten.* Dies ist ein [Pluraletantum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluraletantum).

In Deinem Beispiel verwendest Du *Daten* klar im letzteren Sinne und stößt daher auf Probleme, da das Wort keinen Singular hat. Also kannst Du nur schreiben:

> Ohne die ausdrückliche Einwilligung der jeweiligen Person **dürfen keine der hier angezeigten Daten** an Personen außerhalb des Vereins weitergegeben werden.

Hättest Du stattdessen *Daten* im ersten Sinne verwendet, wäre Deine Konstruktion richtig gewesen, z. B.:

> Ich habe einen Blick in meinen Kalender geworfen: Keines der vorgeschlagenen Daten passt.

Als Alternative kannst Du auch statt *Daten* ein Wort benutzen, das kein Pluraletantum ist, z. B. *Informationen:*

> Ohne die ausdrückliche Einwilligung der jeweiligen Person **darf keine der hier angezeigten Informationen** an Personen außerhalb des Vereins weitergegeben werden.

Comment: Daten sind keine Informationen: Um aus Daten Informationen zu machen, muss man diese Daten interpretieren. Die Abfolge von Nullen und Einsen in einer **Datei** (nicht **Informei**!) sind Daten. Das Bild oder Musikstück, dass ein Computer aus diesen Daten generiert, das sind Informationen. Ohne den Computer (oder einen vergleichbaren Mechanismus), der die Daten richtig interpretiert, können aus den Daten keine Informationen werden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... das stimmt. Der Informationsgehalt einer Datei kann eine andere Größe haben als die Datenmenge. Allerdings glaube ich, dass das hier unerheblich ist. Für Otto-Normal-User sind die Begriffe in diesem Satz Synonym, da das Ergebnis synonym ist. Und wenn man wirklich so strikt trennen wollte, müsste man BEIDES ausschließen. Die weitergabe der Daten SOWIE die Weitergabe der Information.

Comment: Mal abgesehen davon, dass es im vorliegenden Fall keinen Unterschied macht (bzw. nach dieser Interpretation der Worte *Informationen* sogar eher das gewünschte ist), stimmt dies nicht mit dem üblichen, vielfältigen Gebrauch der Wörter überein, wonach insbesondere alle Daten auch Informationen sind, wenn auch ohne Interpretation oft keine besonders nützlichen. Zum Beispiel gibt der Duden als eine Definition von Daten *elektronisch gespeicherte Informationen* an.

Comment: Wrzlprmft & @Emanuel: Danke, durch euch ist mir klar geworden, dass auf der Seite nicht Daten, sondern Informationen angezeigt werden. Damit kann ich das Grammatik-Problem umgehen. Ich widerspreche aber dennoch der Behauptung »Daten« wäre ein Pluraletantum. Auf der Wikipedia-Seite über Daten steht u.a. dieser Satz: »Gleichwohl ist „Datum“ der korrekte Singular zu „Daten“ und kann so auch Anwendung finden.« Wiktionary behauptet zwar das Gegenteil, aber das halte ich für falsch. Die Seite deutsche-rechtschreibung.org stellt nur fest, dass das einige Leute so, und die anderen anders sehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... das ist ja schön und gut, wenn das bei Wikipedia so steht, aber solange ich keine Belege dafür habe, dass das Wort auch tatsächlich so benutzt wird, ist die Wikipedia für mich falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: In dem Artikel scheint jemand rumgeschrieben zu haben, der eine sehr dogmatische Auffassung von Sprache hatte. Nebenbei beobachtet auch der Duden, dass *Daten* ein Pluraletantum ist und dass Du Deinen Beispielsatz als falsch empfandest spricht stark dafür, dass Dein Sprachzentrum diese Einschätzung teilt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: In *meinem* Duden (23. Auflage) steht: »**Da|ten** (*Plur.* von Datum; Zahlenwerte, Angaben)« und: »**Da|tum**, das; -s, ...ten; *vgl.* Daten«. Dort ist also keineswegs die Rede von einem Pluraletantum. In der 39. Auflage des ÖWB steht: »**Da|ten** (Pl.): gesammelte Informationen; Angaben über Ort, Zeit und andere Tatsachen; persönliche D.; D. verarbeitend | → Datum«, und der Eintrag zu Datum lautet: »**Da|tum** das -s/Daten; eine bestimmte Zeitangabe, Geburtsdatum«. Auch daraus fällt es schwer auf ein Pluraletantum zu schließen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Schau mal [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Daten) unter *Grammatik.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ja, und dort steht groß und deutlich in der Liste der Bedeutungen an erster Stelle: »1. Plural von Datum«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ja, das steht dort, aber das ist falsch, denn das eine widerspricht dem anderen. Wörter wie *Gezeiten*, *Kosten* oder *Leute* sind Pluraliatantum, denn das sind Wörter, für die es keine Einzahlform gibt. Sie sind nicht der Plural einer anderen Wortform. Das ist die definierende Eigenschaft eines Pluraletantums. Wenn ein Wort aber der Plural eines anderen, existierenden Wortes ist, folglich zu diesem Wort eine Singularform existiert, dann kann es sich nicht um ein Pluraletantum handeln.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Du kannst das gerne so definieren, aber damit verpasst Du das Wesentliche, nämlich den Gebrauch. Zu vielen Pluraliatantum existieren Singulare, die nur unter gewissen Umständen oder in bestimmten Fachsprachen gebraucht werden, z. B. *Gezeit, Elter, Einkunft, Möbel.* Und *Daten* hat eben nur, wenn es mit einer bestimmten Bedeutung benutzt wird, einen Singular und ist sonst ein Pluraletantum.

Comment: Der Duden-Eintrag hierzu ist zwar zugegebenermaßen suboptimal, aber ich denke es ist keine ausufernde Interpretation, dass er so gedacht ist, dass sich die Angabe *Pluraletantum* nicht auf Bedeutung 1 bezieht, die ihrerseits nur der Vollständigkeit halber dort steht.

Answer (score 4):

Warum klingt es falsch?

Weil wir für Computerdaten nur "die Daten" kennen, und keinen Singular. Wir haben noch nie "das" im Zusammenhang mit Computerdaten gehört und ich glaube, den wenigsten ist bewusst, dass die Einzahl von Daten Datum ist.

Wie kann man das besser formulieren?

Ich sehe keinen Weg daran vorbei "Daten" im Plural zu behalten. Wenn man trotzdem Wert darauf legt, explizit auch eine Weitergabe eines Teils auszuschließen, dann wäre meine Lösung folgende

> Ohne die ausdrückliche Einwilligung der jeweiligen Person dürfen die hier angezeigten Daten weder ganz/komplett noch teilweise an Personen … werden.